# Programmatically UISearchBar not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I created a programatically **UISearchBar** (not UISearchController) and I set it as `tableview` header. However, it's not showing up. Anyone might know why is that?

Outside of the class:

`var searchBar = UISearchBar()`

Inside the **viewDidLoad** method.

```
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.54, green:0.77, blue:0.80, alpha:1.0)
    searchBar.placeholder = "Cauta cheltuieli"
    searchBar.backgroundImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "searchbarback")

    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 44), animated: true)
```

Comment: Show us how you create the searchbar. Maybe the sizes are not set or magic happens before we can’t know that.

Comment: That is exactly how I made the searchbar, as presented in my question.

Comment: Give it a frame: CGRect with the right width and height. (Eg 40 height and tableView.frame.width as width) It does not have a size like this so it will be less then 1px size and you should be good.

Comment: I think you probably need to define dimensions in the initializer. Something like `UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, height: something, width: something))`. Also, I don't think it should be outside of the class.

Comment: Well setting the frame worked! Thank you guys! @BennX answer this question so I can approve your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to give the searchbar any dimension so the size will be zero.

Try setting the dimension by setting the frame or use the constructor with a frame.

```
let searchbar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, height: 50.0, width: tableView.frame.width))
```